# Delete object with certain key value from filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering

I have an array of objects and I filtering it:

```
const test = [
  {
    "id":2,
    "category_id":1,
    "features":["blah","blah","blah","blah"],
    "options":
    {
      "option1":
        {
          "b":22,"c":105,"d":70,"e":345
        },
      "option2":
        {
          "c":25,"c":41,"d":70,"e":345
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "category_id":2,
    "features":["blah","blah","blah","blah"],
    "options":
    {
      "option1":
        {
          "b":22,"c":105,"d":70,"e":345
        },
      "option2":
        {
          "c":25,"c":41,"d":70,"e":345
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "id":7,
    "category_id":4,
    "features":null,
    "options":null
  },
  {
    "id":11,
    "category_id":6,
    "features":["blah","blah","blah","blah"],
    "options":
    {
      "option1":
        {
          "b":22,"c":105,"d":70,"e":345
        },
      "option2":
        {
          "c":25,"c":41,"d":70,"e":345
        }
    }
  }
]


const filtered = test.filter((t) => {


})
```

Objects with "category_id: 4" don't have "options" but inside the `filter` I need all options value that exist:

```
const filtered = test.filter((t) => {
  const tOptions = Object.values(t.options)

})
```

it gives me an error because some options does't exist. 
I know how to modify an array and delete objects without options (with Lodash)

```
_.reject(test, function(el) { return el.category_id === 4 })
```

but I can't modify "test" array because of the logic that goes after.
Somehow I need this result without touching an array itself:

```
[
 Object 
 {
  b:22,
  c:105,
  d:70,
  e:345
 }, 
Object 
 {
  c:41,
  d: 70,
  e: 345
 }
]
```

I really give up. Please help.

Comment: Just check to see if `options` exists before getting the values. E.g., `const tOptinos = t.options ? Object.values(t.options) : [];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if condition to check if t.options is not null

```
const filtered = test.filter((t) => {
  if(t.options) { // null and undefined are falsey
     const tOptions = Object.values(t.options);

  } else {
      return false;
  }
});
``
```

Comment: you are totally right! Thanks, I think I tried to think too hard to solve this problem =)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try  copy object test use (.. your object) or array.splice(index, number of elements, element, element)  or slice() good luck